# Android: Coroutine doesn't always work on call

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

I am working on an app which has a *RecyclerView* inside a *Fragment*. The objective of the *Fragment*, is to fetch with a cursor *Tracks*'s data. Since this process is long, I decide to implement a *ViewModel*, using a coroutine to let the processes work faster.

However, I have a problem with this: the coroutine doesn't always start as it should. For some reason, when I open the app, sometimes the coroutine executes as soon as the *Fragment* gets opened, showing then the proper data inside the *RecyclerView*, and sometimes it doesn't.

**What happens (left) and what should happen (right):**

[image: What happens]
[image: What should happen]

**What is happening? Is there a way to fix this?**

**Fragment.kt**

```
class FragmentTrack : Fragment(), AdapterOneColumn.OnItemClickListener {
    var trackList = mutableListOf<DataItems>()

    ....

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        ....

        if(trackList.isEmpty()) {
            val cttResolver : ContentResolver? = activity?.contentResolver
            ViewModelCycleTracks().recyclerNeedsTracks(trackList, cttResolver)
        }

        rvTracks.apply {
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
            adapter = AdapterOneColumn(trackList, this@FragmentTrack)
        }
    }

    override fun OnItemClick(position: Int) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Pressed song", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

}
```

**ViewModel.kt**

```
class ViewModelCycleTracks : ViewModel() {
    fun recyclerNeedsTracks(trackList: MutableList<DataItems>, cttResolver: ContentResolver?) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            cycleFiles(trackList, cttResolver)
        }
    }

    suspend fun cycleFiles(trackList: MutableList<DataItems>, cttResolver: ContentResolver?) {
        return GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) {

            var songCursor : Unit? = cttResolver?.query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null)?.use {cursor ->
                val idSongName = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE)
                val idSongArtist = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST)
                val idSongArt = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID)

                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    val songName = cursor.getString(idSongName)
                    val songArtist = cursor.getString(idSongArtist)
                    val songArt = cursor.getString(idSongArt)

                    trackList.add(DataItems(songName, songArtist))
                }

            }
        }.await()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the code, the coroutine wouldn't start in case the condition `if(trackList.isEmpty())` is `false`. This happens if the view representation of `FragmentTrack` gets destroyed when navigating to another *Fragment*, while the `FragmentTrack` instance remains alive with the `trackList` being non-empty after the 1st run. When you navigate back to `FragmentTrack`, `trackList` isn't empty, so the coroutine won't launch resulting in an "empty" `RecyclerView`.

Removing the `if(trackList.isEmpty())` check should fix it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224144/discussion-between-onik-and-meltix).